# Java library to manipulate sound files

Tags: android, library, java, audio

I'm looking for a Java library to manipulate sound files. 
My goal is to use it in my android app. I want the user to be able to record his voice by microphone, which already works. But now I need a way to manipulate this sound file in order to make the recorded voice sound like a parrot or a robot. Basically I need to distort the sound files. 
Is there a Java library that already allows the easy manipulation and distortion of sound files in an Android app?